# Pushing values into an array and the first value pushed always ends up in the middle

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, redux

I am pushing values into an array and the first value I push always ends up in the middle. I am making a snake game and the movement of the body is hard to do so I ended up going with just storing the last positions of where the head was to later make the body take that position but the problem is when I push the coordinates of the head and keep constantly doing that because of the interval the coordinates are out of order and the first one ends up in the middle and it spreads inward outward.

At first, I was just using react state to track the last head positions and I thought that might of been an issue so I switched to tracking it in redux, still the same issue. Maybe the issue is that the code is async and the intervals might skip each other but that doesn't explain why it's perfectly adding values inward outward.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { updateCordinates, saveLastPosition } from '../../actions/cordinates';
import SnakeBody from './SnakeBody';

class Player extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // Player position
        this.state = {
            headPosition: {
                position: 'relative',
                left: 0,
                top: 0
            },
            intervals: {
                moveLeftInterval: '',
                moveRightInterval: '',
                moveDownInterval: '',
                moveUpInterval: ''
            }
        }

        this.clearIntervals = this.clearIntervals.bind(this);
        this.moveLeft = this.moveLeft.bind(this);
        this.moveRight = this.moveRight.bind(this);
        this.moveDown = this.moveDown.bind(this);
        this.moveUp = this.moveUp.bind(this);
        this.onKeyDown = this.onKeyDown.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        document.addEventListener("keydown", this.onKeyDown, false);
    }
    componentWillUnmount(){
        document.removeEventListener("keydown", this.onKeyDown, false);
    }
    clearIntervals() {
        const intervals = Object.values(this.state.intervals);

        intervals.forEach((interval) => {
            if (interval) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                this.setState(() => {
                    return {
                        intervals: {
                            moveLeftInterval: '',
                            moveRightInterval: '',
                            moveDownInterval: '',
                            moveUpInterval: ''
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
    getLastPositions(headPosition) {
        const newArr = [ headPosition ];
        for (let i = 0; i < this.state.lastHeadPositions.length ; i++) {
            newArr.push(this.state.lastHeadPositions[i])
        }

        return newArr;
    }
    async moveLeft() {
        const moveLeftInterval = setInterval( async () => {
            await this.setState((prevState) => {
                const headPosition = {
                    position: 'relative',
                    left: prevState.headPosition.left - 25,
                    top: prevState.headPosition.top
                }

                this.props.saveLastPosition(headPosition)

                return {
                    headPosition
                }
            })

        }, 150)

        this.setState((prevState) => {
            return {
                intervals: {
                    ...prevState.intervals,
                    moveLeftInterval
                }
            }
        })
    }
    async moveRight() {
        const moveRightInterval = setInterval( async () => {
            await this.setState((prevState) => {

                const headPosition = {
                    position: 'relative',
                    left: prevState.headPosition.left + 25,
                    top: prevState.headPosition.top
                }
                this.props.saveLastPosition(headPosition)
                return {
                    headPosition
                }
            })

        }, 150);

        this.setState((prevState) => {
            return {
                intervals: {
                    ...prevState.intervals,
                    moveRightInterval
                }
            }
        })
    }
    async moveDown() {
        const moveDownInterval = setInterval( async () => {
            await this.setState((prevState) => {
                const headPosition = {
                    position: 'relative',
                    left: prevState.headPosition.left,
                    top: prevState.headPosition.top + 25
                }
                this.props.saveLastPosition(headPosition)
                return {
                    headPosition
                }
            })

        }, 150)

        await this.setState((prevState) => {
            return {
                intervals: {
                    ...prevState.intervals,
                    moveDownInterval
                }
            }
        })
    }
    async moveUp() {
        const moveUpInterval = setInterval( async () => {
            await this.setState((prevState) => {
                const headPosition = {
                    position: 'relative',
                    left: prevState.headPosition.left,
                    top: prevState.headPosition.top - 25
                }
                this.props.saveLastPosition(headPosition)
                return {
                    headPosition
                }
            })

        }, 150)

        this.setState((prevState) => {
            return {
                intervals: {
                    ...prevState.intervals,
                    moveUpInterval
                }
            }
        })
    }
    async onKeyDown(e) {
        switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 40:
                this.props.saveLastPosition(this.state.headPosition);
                this.clearIntervals();
                return this.moveDown();
            case 39:
                this.props.saveLastPosition(this.state.headPosition);
                this.clearIntervals();
                return this.moveRight();
            case 38:
                this.props.saveLastPosition(this.state.headPosition);
                this.clearIntervals();
                return this.moveUp();
            case 37:
                this.clearIntervals();
                return this.moveLeft();
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div style={this.state.headPosition} className='player'>
                {this.props.snakeLength.length > 0 && this.props.snakeLength.map((elem, index) => {
                    return (
                        <SnakeBody index={index}/>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        );
    };
} 

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    updateCordinates: (cordinates) => dispatch(updateCordinates(cordinates)),
    saveLastPosition: (cordinates) => dispatch(saveLastPosition(cordinates))
})

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Player);
```

The reducer to track cordinates.

```js
import { SAVE_LAST_POSITION } from '../types/types';

const playerPositionsReducer = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SAVE_LAST_POSITION:
            return [...state, action.payload];
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default playerPositionsReducer
```

Action being used

```js
export const saveLastPosition = (payload) => ({
    type: SAVE_LAST_POSITION,
    payload
})
```

screenshot to what the redux state looks like. left: 0, top: 0 is the starting coordinate and from there it pushes inward out.
https://prnt.sc/orczvx

Comment: I think you hit it when u said *"the code is async"*.

Comment: yeah but that doesn't explain why it's perfectly symmetrical inward out. I added awaits on the parts I think mattered. thanks for the input though

Comment: If you want, I can look into the code for you.